Timezone Issue: Aisa/Almaty Changed from GMT+6 to GMT+5 on Feb 29th, 2024,Dayjs Libraries Not Updated
Recently, Aisa/Almaty's timezone was changed from GMT+6 to GMT+5 effective February 29th, 2024. However, it appears that the libraries are not yet updated to reflect this change, resulting in a one-hour discrepancy in real-world time.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there any workarounds or updates available to fix this timezone difference?
We tried updating the current Dayjs library to get the latest changes, but it still doesn't reflect the new timezone
